# Calcular k-mers de sequências de DNA em um arquivo fasta- No python

Tags: python, fasta

Quero calcular a quantidade de k-mers em uma sequência de dna. No entanto, o arquivo que tenho têm várias sequências e também identificadores .

Obs: k-mers são os comprimentos de uma sequencia por exemplo uma sequencia "AAC" se eu quero calcular o kmer =1 seria A=2 C=1 se fosse k=2 seria AA=1  AC=1. Se fosse k=3 (o máximo para essa sequência) seria AAC=1

Por exemplo:

> m54200_170907_19495
>   GGGTTACTGACATGTCTTGCATAATACTTAACTTCTTAGCTGGGACGTAGTCTATACTCG
>   TTTTCAACCTCCAGTTTTCCTTTCTTTTTCTTTCTCTTTTCTTTTTCTTTTGTTTTCCTC
>   TTGTTTTTTGTTTGGAGAGGGCACCCTTAGTACGAAGAACTGACTTTAAGCGGTTTATTGCTGCCGGACATAA
>
> m53000_170907_194957
>   TTTAGCAGCCCAAAAAAAAGATAGAAATATTTATAAATAAGAAAGAAAAATGATATGTAA
>   TGTCTAAAACAGGTTTACATTATCGTGATTTTGTTATATTTATAGAGTTTTAAATATCAG
>   CGTATGTCACATATAGGATTTATGCATTGATGAATTTAGAAGATAACTTACACACCAATT
>   TTAGTAGGGCTGAAATCTCTATTAGTAGAGAATTATATAATTTAAC

Eu consigo calcular os k-mers para o arquivo todo, de forma que ele calcula também o kmer que contém o ID também, mas gostaria que calculasse a partir da sequência , sem contar os identificadores.

```
# Importando a Biblioteca SeqIO
from Bio import SeqIO

# Lendo o arquivo fasta em uma lista
seq_records = list(SeqIO.parse("filee.fasta", 'fasta'))

# Criando uma função para ler a quantidade de k-mers
def kmers(seq_records,k):
    kfreq = {}
    for i in seq_records:
        kmer= seq_records[i:i+k].seq
        if kmer in kfreq:
            kfreq[kmer]+ =1
        else:
            kfreq[kmer] =1

    return kfreq

#Chamando a função e colocando um kmer =2
rf = kmers(seq_records,2)
print(rf)
```

Comment: Talvez [isso](https://github.com/MindAI/kmer/blob/master/kmer.py) possa ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Teste isso

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def build_kmers(sequence, ksize):
    kmers = []
    n_kmers = len(sequence) - ksize + 1

    for i in range(n_kmers):
        kmer = sequence[i:i + ksize]
        kmers.append(kmer)

    return kmers, n_kmers

seq_records = list(SeqIO.parse("sequence.fasta", 'fasta'))

for x in seq_records:
    re = build_kmers(x.seq, 2)
    print(re[1])
```

Você pode verificar mais em [Uma introdução aos k-mers para comparação e análise de genoma](https://sourmash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kmers-and-minhash.html)

Comment: Lucas palheta obrigada pela ajuda